# Relation between a Tensorial derivation and a tensor field of kind $(1,2)$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

I'm trying to prove the next:

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a tensor derivation on $M.$ Relative to a coordinate system,

a) if $\mathcal{D}(\partial_{i})=\sum F_{i}^{j}\partial_{j},$ show that $\mathcal{D}(dx^{j})=-\sum F_{i}^{j}dx^{i}.$

b) If $A$ is a $(1,2)$ tensor field, find a formula for the components of $\mathcal{D}A$ in terms of $F_{i}^{j}$ and the components of $A.$

To prove a) we can use that, for a one-form, $(\mathcal{D}\theta)(X)=\mathcal{D}(\theta X)-\theta(\mathcal{D}X).$ Then 
$$\mathcal{D}(dx^{i})(\partial_{j})=\mathcal{D}(dx^{i}(\partial_{j}))-dx^{i}(\mathcal{D}\partial_{j})=-dx^{i}(\sum F_{j}^{k}\partial_{k})=-F_{j}^{i}.$$

Then $\mathcal{D}(dx^{i})=-\sum F_{j}^{i}dx^{j}.$

For part b) I'm stuck. Could you give me a hand with this?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Write down $A$ in that coordinate you choose to define $\mathcal{D}$ and then apply a).

Comment: Ok. I'll try it.